# Media/Images being deleted without warning?

Tags: 8, files, media

Over the weekend at some point, my dev site lost 75% of the uploaded images. A lot are marked 0 in the database, and don't appear to exist on the physical file system anymore. I don't see anything in the log pertaining as to what or why, and nothing major was deployed on the previous Friday that could have caused this.

Since that point, I have set "Delete Orphaned files after" setting in Drupal core to "Never", because I could not think of anything else that may have caused this. All of the fields are media fields hooked up to Media Entity and Media Entity Image.

Has anyone experienced this behavior or know what may have happeend?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2821423

Comment: @mradcliffe, this issue is for file entities. Didn't find a similar issue for media entities.